# How to Backup migrations folder

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

accidentally i deleted migrations folder in my project how to get backup all my migrations from the migration history table? Is resetting migrations the only option available?

Comment: You can create the only one new migration instead of deleted ones and replace rows at `__MigrationHistory` table.

Comment: In that case if I want to roll back to a particular migration how will i do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, at this case you can't do it